# Cordova camera resize on orientation change

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

When taking a photo via `navigator.camera.getPicture` and changing the device's orientation inside the photo interface, the webview's viewport doesn't resize upon returning. The blank space is not part of the HTML document, so internal resizing in the app doesn't help.

A plugin bug? Is there a way to force resizing on the cordova / webview layer?

That's the result of starting vertical, opening the photo interface, turning into horizontal and returning to the app:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was just fixed with `cordova-plugin-statusbar@2.2.0`

Answer (score 0):

Dirty fix after returning from the camera interface:

```
fixCordovaCameraBug: function() {
    if (... == 'iOS') {
        var actions = window.StatusBar.isVisible ? ['hide', 'show'] : ['show', 'hide'];
        window.StatusBar[actions[0]]();
        window.StatusBar[actions[1]]();
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            // framework specific
            Ext.GlobalEvents.fireResize();
        }, 1);
    }
},
```